# Creating a composite ID using a ManyToOne relation definition

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

Hibernate requires an ID for my Entity:

(throws *org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity*)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILDREN")
public class ChildDb {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INNER_ID", nullable = false)
    private ParentDb parent;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private double value;
}
```

Here's the parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentDb {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "INNER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G1")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "SOME_SEQ")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP")
    private long timestamp;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<ChildDb> children;
}
```

BUT, the id should be composite - parent ID and name.

How to define this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe doing this will work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILDREN")
public class ChildDb implements Serializable{

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "INNER_ID", nullable = false)
private ParentDb parent;

@Id
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "VALUE")
private double value;
```

}

Comment: Why do you believe this would work? Can you point to some documentation? Perhaps tutorials doing this?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier

Comment: Didn't work. When I added the @Id annotation to the parent variable, I got the following error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ChildDb.parent in ParentDb.children`

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I think that your problem could be on the other side of the relationship, Can you update your question with the ParentDb definition?

Comment: @Skizzo - I added the parent's definition to the question.

Comment: one thing I missed is that the ChildDb class needs to implement the Serializable interface

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the strange thing that you do could be this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "INNER_ID", nullable = false)
private ParentDb parent;
```

Do you have an "INNER_ID" also in you ChildDB. In case of OneToMany relationship the @ManyToOne side has to be the owner of the foreign key.

Comment: What do you mean by 'owner of the foreign key'? How do you own a foreign key?

Comment: I already update the question with how the parent looks like.

Comment: Con you show also the database structure, I ha ve same sound about the INNER_ID because you are using the INNER_ID column on boy side